# Django: Group by?

Tags: python, django, group-by, django-orm

I'm looking for something like the following:

```
previous_invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(is_open=False)
                                   .order_by('-created')
                                   .group_by('user')
```

but `group_by()` doesn't exist...

This would find the most recently closed invoice for each user.

This [aggregation API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/) seems to let you do stuff like this for counts and sums, but I don't need a count or sum or anything, I actually want the invoice objects!

Comment: is the *selected* thing even defined when using group by? I would expect it to yield different results depending on sql implementation...

Comment: @user3012759 No. The ordering happens after grouping, which record you get back within that group is undefined. It took me awhile to really understand that. [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) should be enabled by default IMO so that you don't make that mistake.

Comment: Hey @mpen I added an more recent attempt to answer. Care to take a look?

Comment: @JohnMoutafis Sure I can look. I don't work with Django anymore, but that looks like it'd be helpful if I did :-)

Comment: Good to know @mpen :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Although a `group_by()` does not exist in Django, you can try and work around on retrieving the most recently closed invoice for each user by utilizing [`latest()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#latest) method and filter for a user as well:

```
previous_invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(user=my_user, is_open=False)
                                   .latest('created')
```

For older versions of Django were `latest()` does not exist, the query will look like this:

```
previous_invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(user=my_user, is_open=False)
                                   .order_by('-created')[0]
```

---

**Option 2:**

*UPDATE: I have since then added a Q&A style example here: [How to execute a GROUP BY ... COUNT or SUM in Django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547674/how-to-execute-a-group-by-count-or-sum-in-django-orm?noredirect=1&lq=1) that shows how to simulate a `GROUP BY` operation on Django ORM.*

If you absolutely want to create the effects of a `group_by`, then you can create one manually as shown in the accepted answer here: [Django GROUP BY field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163299/django-group-by-field-value?answertab=votes#tab-top).

> 1. Use [`.values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) with `flat=True` to get a list of the existent values in your database (if you don't know them beforehand). Also use `.distinct()` to eliminate duplicate values as we do not care for those:
>
>    ```
>    value_list = MyModel.objects.values_list(
>        'interesting_field', flat=True
>    ).distinct()
>    ```
> 2. Now iterate through `value_list` and fill your dictionary:
>
>    ```
>    group_by_value = {}
>    for value in value_list:
>        group_by_value[value] = MyModel.objects.filter(interesting_field=value)
>    ```
>
> Now `group_by_value` dictionary contains as keys the distinct values
>   in your `interesting_field` and as values the queryset objects, each
>   containing the entries of `MyModel` with `interesting_field=a value
>   from value_list`.

---

**Note:**

There exists this library [django-group-by](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-group-by) which claims to add a `group_by()` on Django you may want to check.

Answer (score 2):

There's [this page from 2007](http://blog.awarelabs.com/2007/modify-django-to-support-group-by-query-function/) who hacked it to django, but that would be moot since pre 1.1 does have an undocumented group_by` anyway. But [this thread from a year ago](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/15b3c24dddd2a2d5) seems to have some insights. Essentially:

> Django intentionally does not expose "GROUP BY" or anything like that, in
>   the ORM. Although the fact that we're
>   over a relational storage backend
>   sometimes leaks through, the ORM API
>   is fairly SQL-agnostic. Instead, we
>   expose particular pieces of
>   functionality that happen to be
>   implemented using "GROUP BY" when it's
>   turned into SQL (and could well be
>   implemented by some entirely different
>   set of magical fairies with a
>   different storage system backend).

See also the mentions of using `extra`, and also the magical ways in which *that* can fail. Best of luck.