# Django order_by() and distinct(<field>) w/ annotate

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm using Django 1.4 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 13.04.

I know there are issues with using `order_by()` and `distinct()` across relationships in Django.  It seems most of the suggested solutions to overcome this is to use aggregation.  I'm not seeing how I can do this in my case.

I have a `QuerySet` that has been pre-filtered.  I need to order it by 2 fields and then get the results by a distinct foreign key.

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    rpl = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Offer(models.Model):
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

I need to get a list of offers ordered first by contract priority then contract rpl.  Of that result I need the offers with distinct products.

`qs.order_by('-contract__priority', '-contract__rpl').distinct('product')`

How would I do this elegantly with Django?

Comment: this might be case for .raw (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/)?               I happen to like SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you need is a GROUP BY statement, and unfortunately django doesn't offer that - see this question [Django: Group by?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436939/django-group-by)

Personally I'd probably approach it from a different angle, and use a Product queryset instead. You can filter on offer fields and order by annotated priority/rpl values, then for each product you'd need to retrieve the offer details separately. It means an extra query for each row, but it might be the best you can do. Eg:

```
Product.objects.filter(offer__...=...) \
               .annotate(priority=models.Max('offer__contract__priority'),
                         rpl=models.Max('offer__contract__rpl')) \ 
               .order_by('-priority', '-rpl')
```