# Django GROUP BY field value

Tags: python, django

Surprising that I could not find a way to make a group by query.

I have a query set `qs` and I am trying to group by `some_prop.val`, considering `qs` is excluding entries where `some_prop` is `None`.

Let's say the values are `[1, 2, 3]`, then I would be after a result like this:

```
{1: entries1, 2: entries2, 3: entries3}
```

Does the Django ORM provide any feature to group results like this?

Comment: If you can post more about what query you tried it would be beneficial for us to answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is not a specific Django ORM way (as far as I know) but you can do the following to get a dictionary of entries grouped by the values of a field:

1. Use [`.values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) with `flat=True` to get a list of the existent values in your database (if you don't know them beforehand). Also, use `.distinct()` to eliminate duplicate values as we do not care for those:

   ```
   value_list = MyModel.objects.values_list(
       'interesting_field', flat=True
   ).distinct()
   ```
2. Iterate through `value_list` and fill your dictionary:

   ```
   group_by_value = {}
   for value in value_list:
       group_by_value[value] = MyModel.objects.filter(interesting_field=value)
   ```

Now, the `group_by_value` dictionary contains as keys the distinct values in your `interesting_field` and as values the queryset objects, each containing the entries of `MyModel` with `interesting_field=a value from value_list`.

---

---

**Leaving this here for comment legacy reasons.**

I have made a [Q&A style example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547674/how-to-execute-a-group-by-count-or-sum-in-django-orm/45547675#45547675) in, which simulates a `COUNT ... GROUP BY` SQL query.

Essentially you need to utilize the [`.order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) for grouping and the [`.annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to count on the model's [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values).

Here is the above-mentioned example:

> We can perform a `COUNT ... GROUP BY` SQL equivalent query on Django ORM, with the use of `annotate()`, `values()`, `order_by()` and the
> `django.db.models`'s `Count` methods:
>
> Let our model be:
>
> ```
> class Books(models.Model):
>     title  = models.CharField()
>     author = models.CharField()
> ```
>
> Let's assume that we want to count how many book objects per distinct author exist in our Book table:
>
> ```
> result = Books.objects.values('author')
>                       .order_by('author')
>                       .annotate(count=Count('author'))
> ```
>
> Now result contains a queryset with two columns: author and count:
>
> ```
>   author    | count
> ------------|-------  
>  OneAuthor  |   5 
> OtherAuthor |   2    
>    ...      |  ...
> ```

Comment: yeah but I do not want to group by count, I said very clearly I wanted to group by **values**, how could I be more clear? I even included the expected output.